# Can we search for public objects shared by our friends using graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to search for comments on keyword using graph API

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY
that lists for me a very large set of results.

For example: 
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon
gives me a large set of results in JSON format over pages.Is there any method to get results which are posted by my friends only.?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Have you read this : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ ?

Comment: @TrimbitasSorin yes.I checked it.According to that there isnt any open graph methods to filter friends.
Is there any other methods?

Comment: Well, if the API itself don't provide a method for this .. you can create it by yourself or find a workaround by mixing different api calls (raw example : get your list of friends, for each of them get comments, filter the results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **Search**, you can search over all public objects in the social graph. Since, you are limiting your search to the user's friends, simply use this-

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?q=watermelon
```